# Umbraco Examine: how to search inside Embedded Content data type?

Tags: lucene, umbraco

I'm using the Embedded Content data type (http://farmcode.org/post/2011/01/20/Presenting-a-new-Umbraco-data-type-Embedded-Content.aspx) and I can't seem to find a way to properly use Umbraco Examine to search inside the Embedded Content data type.

The search result object returned presents the Embedded Content type as a string with all the fields mashed together, and not in the original xml format.

Is there a way around this so I can search individual fields inside the embedded content type?

Comment: solved!... to see solution go to: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/31632-Umbraco-Examine-how-to-search-inside-Embedded-Content-data-type?p=0#comment117290

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered on the [Umbraco forum](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/31632-Umbraco-Examine-how-to-search-inside-Embedded-Content-data-type?p=0#comment117290) (as metnoied in the comment above), to surmise:

When indexing content that is stored in a XML or other custom format, you need to pre-process the data before you insert it into the Lucene index.

You can do this by hooking into the `GatheringNodeData` event in Examine. You then process the XML and save the data into a new field. You can do this with all sorts of custom data types.

Full details can be found here:

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/31632-Umbraco-Examine-how-to-search-inside-Embedded-Content-data-type?p=0#comment117290

(Added this answer to aid findability and prevent link rot)